# Perl list interpolation performance

Tags: list, perl

## Background

Perldoc for [List::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#reduce) suggests that some uses of `map` may be replaced by `reduce` in order to avoid creating unnecessary intermadiate list:

> For example, to find the total length of the all the strings in a
>   list, we could use
>
> ```
> $total = sum map { length } @strings;
> ```
>
> However, this produces a list of temporary integer values as long as
>   the original list of strings, only to reduce it down to a single value
>   again. We can compute the same result more efficiently by using reduce
>   with a code block that accumulates lengths by writing this instead as:
>
> ```
> $total = reduce { $a + length $b } 0, @strings;
> ```

That makes sense. However, `reduce` in order to work in this example needs "identity value", that would be prepended to input list:

```
$total = reduce { $a + length $b } 0, @strings;
#                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That makes me think, doesn't `0, @strings` create a new list, thus offset any gains from not creaing list in `map`?

## Question

How does list interpolation `($scalar, @list)` work in Perl? Does it involve copying elements from source list or is it done in some smarter way? My simple benchmark suggests copying taking place:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark qw/cmpthese/;

my @a1 = 1..10;
my @a2 = 1..100;
my @a3 = 1..1000;
my @a4 = 1..10000;
my @a5 = 1..100000;
my @a6 = 1..1000000;

cmpthese(10000, {
    'a1' => sub { my @l = (0, @a1); },
    'a2' => sub { my @l = (0, @a2); },
    'a3' => sub { my @l = (0, @a3); },
    'a4' => sub { my @l = (0, @a4); },
    'a5' => sub { my @l = (0, @a5); },
    'a6' => sub { my @l = (0, @a6); },
});
```

Results:

```
            (warning: too few iterations for a reliable count)
        Rate       a6       a5       a4       a3       a2       a1
a6    17.6/s       --     -90%     -99%    -100%    -100%    -100%
a5     185/s     952%       --     -90%     -99%    -100%    -100%
a4    1855/s   10438%     902%       --     -90%     -99%    -100%
a3   17857/s  101332%    9545%     862%       --     -91%     -98%
a2  200000/s 1135940%  107920%   10680%    1020%       --     -80%
a1 1000000/s 5680100%  540000%   53800%    5500%     400%       --
```

Bonus question: If my assumptions are correct (i.e. `0, @strings` creates a new list), does replacing `map` with `reduce` make sense?

Comment: You should do your `cmpthese` with a fixed number of CPU seconds. Do `-1` or `-2`. That's more reliable than using a number of runs. Also look into Dumbbench for a more statistical approach of benchmarking.

Comment: Re "*My simple benchmark suggests copying taking place*", Yes, though is a probably an efficient `memcpy` of C pointers

Answer (score 4):

> doesn't `0, @strings` create a new list

Not really. If you [decompile](http://p3rl.org/B::Terse) the code, it's just one additional SVOP.

But you're measuring the wrong thing. The values are flattened and passed into the `map` or `reduce` subroutine in both cases!

The documentation is talking about what happens inside the subroutine. `map` creates a list of as many input values and returns them, and then `sum` takes the list and condenses it into a value. The return list is ephemeral and is not represented directly in the code. (This list passing is not that efficient, it could be made faster by using references.)

In contrast, in `reduce`, there no such return list. `reduce` only works on the input list of values and returns a single value.

Comment: Ok, so there's no extra list copy created by `0,@strings`, but there's new list copy when arguments are assigned to `@_` (or whatever it's called in XS) and that happens both in `map` and `reduce` case, right?

Answer (score 3):

The direct question can be answered directly by a benchmark

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw(sum reduce);    
use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);

my @ary = 1..10_000;

sub by_reduce { my $res = reduce { $a + length $b } 0, @ary }

sub by_map { my $res = sum map { length } @ary }

cmpthese(-3, {
    reduce  => sub { by_reduce  },  
    map     => sub { by_map },
});
```

which prints on my v5.16 at hand

```
         Rate    map reduce
map     780/s     --   -41%
reduce 1312/s    68%     --
```

Thus `reduce` does something significantly better for this task.

As for the question of lists in general, it would have to depend on how the full list is used.

In your benchmark there is an assignment to a new array so the data copy clearly must be done. Then longer arrays take longer, and by about an order of magnitude quite like the ratio of their sizes.

With list inputs for functions like `map` and `reduce` I don't see a reason for an additional data copy.  This can be checked by a benchmark, comparing an identical operation

```
my @ary = 1..10_000;
# benchmark:
my $r1 = sum map { length } @ary;
my $r2 = sum map { length } (1..5000, 5001..10_000);
```

The reported rates are nearly identical, for example`780/s` and `782/s`, showing that the flattening of the ranges for `map` input doesn't involve a data copy.  (The ranges are converted to arrays at compile time, thanks to [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) for comments.)

Comment: On my MBP (mid 2015), using perl 5.20.2, and List::Util version 1.41, I get a similar looking comparison but instead of -41% and 68%, I get -35% and 53%.

Comment: Re "*The reported rates are nearly identical*", That's because `5001..10_000` is converted to a 5000 element array at compile-time. Use `$x = 5000; (1..$x, $x+1..$x*2)` for a better result. (Also note that you have `1_5000` (a single scalar) instead of `1..5000`.)

Comment: @ikegami  Thank you.  (1) The `1_5000` was a typo in posting, fixed  (2) I meant to demonstrate that the apparent flattening of lists for input doesn't introduce an extra data copy.  I think that this should then be the right test? (In my original tests I actually make three arrays in the second case and use `(@beg, @mid, @end)` for the whole range.)

Comment: @ikegami  But now when I try it with `$x` as in your comment -- that is twice as slow!  I am not sure I understand that, but I'd say that it is about things other than what the question asks.

Comment: It's twice as slow since it needs to create 10,000 scalars.

Answer (score 3):

"*This produces a list of temporary integer values as long as the original list of strings*" refers to `map` putting N scalars on the stack.  The thing is, the `reduce` approach creates just as many scalars, and they also all go on the stack. The only difference is that the `reduce` approach only keeps one on them on the stack at once. That means the `reduce` approach uses less *memory*, but it doesn't speak to its *performance* at all. The reason it gives for `reduce` computing the same result more efficiently is nonsense.

There could be a performance difference, but not for that reason. If you want to find which one performs better for you, will need to run a benchmark.

---

> *That makes me think, doesn't `0, @strings` create a new list*

No. `reduce` creates a single list unconditonally. This is unrelated to the number expressions in the argument list.

Lists aren't arrays. When we say "the sub returns a list" or "the op evaluates to a list", we actually mean "the sub or op places some quantity of scalars on the stack".

List are created for ops that will pop a variable number of scalars from the stack. This is done by simply pushing a mark onto the stack. For example, `reduce { ... } 0, @a` would create a list for the `entersub` op. `{ ... }` will end up leaving one code ref on the list/stack, `0` will end up leaving a number on the list/stack, and `@strings` will end up leaving its elements on the list/stack. One last thing is added to the list/stack before the sub is called: the glob `*reduce`.

Note that creating the list is effectively *free*, since it's simply pushing a mark on the stack. Placing an array on the stack is proportional to the number of its elements, but it's still quite cheap since we're only copying a block of pointers (in the C sense of the word).

That means there's effectively no performance difference between `reduce { ... } @strings` and `reduce { ... } 0, @strings`. Both create a single list, and both add roughly the same number of elements to the list/stack.

Exceptions:

- `for (@a)` is optimized to be `for* (\@a)`.
  This saves memory, and it saves time if the loop is exited prematurely.
- `sub f(\@); f(@a)` is equivalent to `&f(\@a)`.

AFAIK, `map` and `grep` aren't optimized in this manner.

---

In detail:

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -MList::Util=reduce -e'reduce { ... } @a'
...
3  <0> pushmark s                        <-- Creates list (adds mark to the stack).
4  <$> anoncode[CV ] sRM                 <-- Adds CV to the stack.
5  <1> srefgen sKM/1                     <-- Replaces CV with a ref to the CV.
6  <#> gv[*a] s                          <-- Places *a on the stack.
7  <1> rv2av[t4] lKM/1                   <-- Replaces *a with the contents of @a.
8  <#> gv[*reduce] s                     <-- Places *reduce on the stack.
9  <1> entersub[t5] vKS/TARG             <-- Will remove the entire list from the stack.
...

$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -MList::Util=reduce -e'reduce { ... } 0, @a'
...
3  <0> pushmark s
4  <$> anoncode[CV ] sRM
5  <1> srefgen sKM/1
6  <$> const[IV 0] sM                    <-- The only difference.
7  <#> gv[*a] s
8  <1> rv2av[t4] lKM/1
9  <#> gv[*reduce] s
a  <1> entersub[t5] vKS/TARG
...
```